# Многопоточность php

Tags: php

Пробую эмулировать многопоточность через

```
system('/usr/bin/wget ...1');
system('/usr/bin/wget ...2');
```

Но экземпляры скрипта 1 и 2 выполняются по очереди, а не одновременно. 
Если в браузере вызвать в двух соседних вкладках один и тот же скрипт, то он опять таки будет выполнятся сначала на одной вкладке, потом на другой. Почему не асинхронно?

Может в php настройки какие-то надо поменять?

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто. Сейчас у вас скрипт "ждёт" когда выполнение команды будет будет закончено перед исполнением следующей. Для параллельного выполнения лучше использовать exec(), и для того, чтобы не ждать ответа - добавьте в конце команды символ &. 
Примерно так:

```
exec('/usr/bin/wget ...1 &');
```

Comment: Попробовал, так же скрипт не выполнялся дальше, пока не выполнится exec. Вообщем, сделал через curl с CURLOPT_TIMEOUT = 1

Comment: @vobpivpobi: Попробуйте, как советуют [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php),

    exec("/usr/bin/wget ...1 >/dev/null &");

Answer (score 2):

php неудобен для асинхронного программирования, потому что у него это не основная задача.

А с асинхронностью хорошо справляется node.js, рекомендую.

Comment: "php неудобен для асинхронного программирования" теперь я это понял :) За node.js спасибо.

Comment: лучшее "спасибо" -- принятый ответ ;)